# Nuxt/Vue.js - Dynamically loading in a child component based on a prop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have a `sectionHeader.vue` component that I want to use on lots of different pages. Inside that `sectionHeader.vue` is a `<canvas>` element (that I am using for some robust three.js animations) that I dynamically want to change inside of each header through props. I'd like to get this working to take advantange of Vue's inherent code-splitting so that each page doesn't load every single other pages animation js code, only the code that is relevant to it.

I'm attempting to dynamically load this in using [dynamic components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components) but I don't think this is what I'm looking for...

My folder structure:

```
components
  animations
    robust-animation-1.vue
    robust-animation-2.vue
    maybe-like-15-more-of-these.vue
  headings
    heading2.vue
  SectionHeader.vue
pages
  index.vue
```

pages/index.vue:

```js
<sectionHeader post-title="Menu" class-name="menu" canvas="./animations/robust-animation-1"></sectionHeader>
```

components/SectionHeader.vue:

```js
<template>
    <section class="intro section-intro" :class="className">
        <heading2 :post-title="postTitle"></heading2>
        <component v-bind:is="canvas"></component> <!-- this is what i am dynamically trying to load --> 
        {{canvas}} <!-- this echos out ./animations/robust-animation-1 -->
    </section>
</template>

<script>
import heading2 from './headings/heading2';

export default {
    components: {
        heading2
    },
    props: [
        'postTitle', 'className', 'canvas'
    ]
}
</script>
```

components/animations/robust-animation-1.vue:

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <canvas class="prowork-canvas" width="960" height="960"></canvas>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
// 200 lines of js here that manipulates the above canvas
</script>
```

My `heading2` component works great, but no matter what I try I can't figure out how to dynamically pull in my animation component. I get varying degrees of the below error:

```
client.js 76 DOMException: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('./animations/robust-animation-1') is not a valid name.
```

I looked into scoped slots, and that looks close to what I need, but not exactly. Is there a better way to do what I'm attempting?

Comment: Can you provide a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) with minimal code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successfully done Dynamically loading in a child component based on a `prop`. Please refer to the following code.

```
components
  animations
    robust-animation-1.vue
    robust-animation-2.vue
    maybe-like-15-more-of-these.vue
  headings
    heading2.vue
  SectionHeader.vue
pages
  index.vue
```

vuepages/index.vue:

```
  <section-header post-title="Menu" class-name="menu" canvas="./animations/robust-animation-1">
  </section-header>
  <script>
    import SectionHeader from "../components/SectionHeader";

    export default {
        name: 'PageIndex',
        components: {SectionHeader}
    }
  </script>
```

components/SectionHeader.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    post_title {{postTitle}}
    <br/>
    class-name {{className}}
    <br/>
    canvas {{canvas}}
    <br/>
    <heading2 post-title="postTitle"></heading2>
    <br/>
    <component v-bind:is="stepComponent"></component>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Heading2 from "./headings/heading2";

    export default {
        name: "SectionHeader",
        components: {
            Heading2,
        },
        props: ['postTitle', 'className', 'canvas'],
        computed: {
            stepComponent() {
                let data = this.canvas.split('/')[2];
                return () => import(`./animations/${data}`);
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

**You're missing that last `computed` step as part of the SectionHeader.vue component**

components/animations/robust-animation-1.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    From - robust-animation-1
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "robust-animation-1"
    }
</script>
```

Output:

```
post_title Menu 
class-name menu 
canvas ./animations/robust-animation-1 
postTitle 
From - robust-animation-1
```